# Почему возникает ошибка "illegal start of expression"?

Tags: java, lambda, predicate

В пятой строке,  которая начинается с `Predicate<String>`, возникает ошибка:

> illegal start of expression

Вот мой код:

```java
import java.util.function.Predicate;

public class Main implements Predicate{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Predicate<String> p1 = s -> return s != null;
        
        p1.test("fgt");
    }
}
```

Как исправить ошибку?

Answer (score 3):

Оператор `return` нужно использовать при применении блока, когда есть какие-то вычисления (отдельная функция).  В данном же случае, чтобы избавиться от ошибки, следовало написать:

```java
Predicate<String> p1 = s -> { return s!= null; };
```

Однако выражение `s != null` достаточно простое и возвращает булевский тип, поэтому конструкция с `return` не нужна:

```java
Predicate<String> p1 = s -> s!= null;
```

---

После разрешения первой ошибки с компиляцией сразу же проявится вторая о том, что класс `Main` должен быть объявлен абстрактным, так как в нём нет реализации метода интерфейса `test(Object)`:

```
/Main.java:3: error: Main is not abstract and does not override abstract method test(Object) in Predicate
public class Main implements Predicate {
       ^
1 error
```

Также появится предупреждение об использовании "сырого" типа `Predicate`.

Либо целью класса не является реализация интерфейса и его нужно объявить просто:

```java
public class Main {
// ...
}
```

либо объявить абстрактным:

```java
public abstract class Main implements Predicate {
// ...
}
```

либо всё-таки реализовать требуемый метод:

```java
public class Main implements Predicate {
    public boolean test(Object obj) {
        return null != obj;
    }
}
```